# how do I generate a patch from one git repo and apply it to a different repo

Tags: git

I have two git repositories with the same code but different parentage i.e. one repo isn't a fork of the other, they were started separately but then the same code was copied into both.

How do I generate a patch file from one repo that will apply to the other. I've tried these steps:

repo1: `git format-patch -1; cp 0001-foo.patch ../repo2`

repo2: `git apply --stat 0001-foo.patch` # ok

repo2: `git apply --check 0001-foo.patch` # gives lots of errors

The errors are like:

```
error: patch failed: bar.cfg:1
error: bar.cfg: patch does not apply
```

Even though the code is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try `git apply -3 0001-foo.patch`.

I prefer `git cherry-pick` when it's possible, because it handles with conflicts in a much more friendly way. Apparently, you have the 2 repositories on the same machine. Try `git cherry-pick`.

```
cd /path/to/repo2

# Fetch the branch containing the commit from repo1 to repo2
git fetch /path/to/repo1 <branch_containing_the_commit>

# Apply the commit
git cherry-pick <commit>

# Resolve the conflicts if any
git add <conflict_paths>
git cherry-pick --continue
```

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning what `-3` does (it does a 3-way merge) and that it requires that the destination repository has the pre-image objects. In a case where repo1 and repo2 are not related (or have diverged widely) this is likely not the case, and then `-3` cannot work. If, OTOH, the repositories are related, `git cherry-pick` *is* the better choice but requires that the histories can be fetched from the source to the destination repo.

Comment: Thanks. -3 didn't work, the repos have different initial git inits. But fetching in repo1 from repo2 then cherry picking worked - I didn't know you could fetch between repos with different git inits.

Comment: @SoniaHamilton A Git repo can work as a client, and also as a server as long as the [Git URL](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#_git_urls) to it is accessible. The local path is among the supported. You can even push to/fetch from a repo itself. For example, `git push . main:dev` is equivalent to `git branch dev main`, creating `dev` based on `main`.